# Disable cache on URLs generated by Htaccess rewrite-mod

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I have a mini costum framework. All URLs are made on the `index.php?op=ControllerName&Action=Methode&elemID=211` for example.

I generate the friendly URL of all specific URLs.
The problem is that I want to disable cache using `.htaccess` on all generated URLs.

So for elem 211 or 215 or 233 etc... I want that the server is getting the page not from cache.
Every time that the `index.php` is called I want that the browser use cache only for CSS, JavaScript, images and not for **mysite.com/211-friendly_URL** or **mysite.com/215-friendly_URL_number_2**

I used this but it didn't work

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
<Files index.php>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</Files>
</ifmodule>
```

thanks for your help;

Comment: To clarify, by "didn't work", you mean those headers were simply not set? There's no obvious reason why this wouldn't work, unless perhaps there is a conflict with something else in your `.htaccess` file or application code? Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.